# Sencha cmd build error: shellscript returned: 1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am working on a pre-existing Sencha Touch project. I am unable to build it and am unsure how I should go about debugging Sencha cmd build issues. Any help either with this specific error or hints regarding how to set up a Sencha build environment would be most appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the error message:

```
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/foo/bartech/bartech2go-new/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:437: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/foo/bartech/bartech2go-new/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/foo/bartech/bartech2go-new/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:109: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/foo/luggage/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.0.202/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:680: shellscript returned: 1
     at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:54)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:120)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:104)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:145)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:280)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:738)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:97)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:346)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:201)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:73)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
     at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/foo/bartech/bartech2go-new/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:437: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/foo/bartech/bartech2go-new/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/foo/bartech/bartech2go-new/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:109: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/foo/luggage/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.0.202/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:680: shellscript returned: 1
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:116)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:104)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:145)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:280)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:738)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:97)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:346)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:201)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:73)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
     at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.10.4. Here are the version numbers of Sencha Cmd and some of its dependencies:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.0.0.202

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)

cordova 5.1.1
```

I am not sure what version Sencha Touch I am running. Here are some hopefully helpful values:

```
.sencha/app/sencha.cfg: app.cmd.version=6.0.0.202

.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg: workspace.cmd.version=5.0.3.324

touch/cmd/sencha.cfg: framework.cmd.version=4.0.5.87
```

Here is a complete build log: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jkndrkn/5fbecd12c3875649687f/raw/sencha-cmd-build-log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that is occuring has something to do with the cordova ios platform files.

I've found that running `cordova platform remove {platform}` from the cordova folder, then re-adding the platform is effective. ( to re-add, `cordova platform add {platform}` )

Comment: You are partially correct. My project was missing almost of all of its cordova files! The original project dev committed it and now the build appears to be working. I will mark your answer as the correct one since it clued me in to the fact that there was an issue with cordova.